# Label Image scale issue in Codename one library 3.3

Tags: image, scale, codenameone

We are using the following code to download image from our server and display it with a label:

```
ImageDownloadService.createImageToStorage(IconSrc, label, IconSrc, 
new Dimension(width,height), ImageDownloadService.PRIORITY_NORMAL);
```

After upgrading to the latest library 3.3, theimages are no longer scaled properly. It either only shows one corner of the image or scales the image up to fill the entire space.

This issue does not occur once I fall back to the older library 3.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code of `ImageDownloadService` I don't quite understand how this functionality worked in the past.

We don't really use that class internally and have recommended that developers migrate to the far superior [URLImage](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/URLImage.html) class. I'll have a look at trying to fix that regression but I'd strongly suggest you migrate your code to the newer API.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try to use URLImage class instead.

Comment: URLImage works as expected and ImageDownloadService is now marked as deprecated. Thanks.